# Is there a file size limit to xarray in python?

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

I want to open a netCDF4 data set using xarray.

I have two examples.  A big file with over 3 million points in the time series (3.2GB). A small file with 9999 points in the time series (9.8 MB).
This code will open the small file.

```
ds = xr.open_dataset(smallfile, chunks={'rec': 3600}, decode_times=False)
```

If I use the big file, I get an unknown error.  The behavior is consistent on two different windows machines with miniconda installed.

What is going on here?  What else should I check for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should add that MATLAB has no problem with the large file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither xarray nor netCDF4-Python have file size limits. They've been used successfully for files in the 10-100GB range.

Your problem looks similar to those reported in this netCDF4-Python issue for reading large files on Windows with Python 3: https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/issues/535

More broadly, you might run into [limitations of the netCDF file format](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/faq.html#Have-all-netCDF-size-limits-been-eliminated) itself. Version 4, which xarray supports via netCDF4-Python and h5netcdf, is based on HDF5 and has no file size limits. Version 3, which xarray supports via netCDF4-Python and scipy, has a 2GB file size limit unless using the "64-bit offset" version (which even then still has a <4GB limit per variable).

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation that size is not the issue.